# make UitextView horizontally scrolling and not truncating the text.

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to make a horizontally scrollable uitextview in which a user can type text that is much longer than the width of the textview.

But currently, when i have implement a textfield, the text stops at the end of the textview, even when i continue to type and setting textContainer.maximumnumberoflines = 1.

I wish it to have the same vertical scrolling function where the height textview expands while users types more text onto the textview. But in my case, i want the width of textview to expand to accommodate words.

At the end of the long text, i wish to be able to scroll the textview horizontally to view the full text.

The current failed attempt by me looks like this. 
[image]

currently, the word stops at "hahahh", no matter how much i type, nothing changes.

Comment: hmmm... do you have some code behind that? The default behavior of a `UITextField` is to allow typing past the end and horizontal scrolling...

Comment: @DonMag UItextfield allows horizontal scrolling? How do i do that?

Comment: Same way you do that with pretty much every text input field on iOS... long-press displays the carat / insertion point indicator... then drag left/right.

Comment: @DonMag after i have typed a long text onto a textfield... i can't seem to scroll to see the other part of text on the textfield... Is there any way i can make it scrollable to see the truncated text?

Comment: If you open Safari on your phone, and type in or go to a long url, are you able to scroll to see/edit the full url?

Comment: @DonMag nope, but i wish to implement something that does the functionality i am asking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139984/discussion-between-donmag-and-progammingbeignner).

Comment: @progammingBeignner what was the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

textContainer.maximumnumberoflines = 1  ---->  This is not required (By default textField has scrolling property). You can initialize textField like this and it works. Here specify your textField frame, superView to which this textField has to be added, color and font.

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
myTextField.font = giveFont;
myTextField.textColor = giveColor;
[superview addSubView:myTextField];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextView instead of TextField.
TextView is located just above the ScrollView in Object Library.

[Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6CrM.png)